# How to convert the Json function to Html/text output golang

Tags: html, json, go, text

I'm trying to convert the api responses to html/text, the original script only prints in json

```
func writeJSONResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, statusCode int, data interface{}) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
}

func writeErrorResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, statusCode int, message string) {
    response := map[string]interface{}{
        "error": message,
        "links": []map[string]string{
            {
                "rel":  "self",
                "href": r.URL.Path,
            },
        },
    }

    writeJSONResponse(w, statusCode, response)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It's returning as `JSON` because you are using `writeJSONResponse`. If you want to response in `HTML` you can create a new function which return `HTML` and use that function instead of `writeJSONResponse`.

Example `writeHTMLResponse` function.

```
func writeHTMLResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, statusCode int, data string) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    w.Write([]byte(data))
}
```